# How do I convert this date range (month,year) date picker to show the output of the month in numeric format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

```
 $( "#SAProstarteDate, #SAProendDate" ).datepicker({ 
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     dateFormat: 'MMyy',            
     onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
          var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
          var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();             
          $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
     },
     beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
         if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
             year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
             month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
             $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
             $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));    
         }
         var other = this.id == "SAProstarteDate" ? "#SAProendDate" : "#SAProstarteDate";
         var option = this.id == "SAProstarteDate" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";        
         if ((selectedDate = $(other).val()).length > 0) {
             year = selectedDate.substring(selectedDate.length-4, selectedDate.length);
             month = jQuery.inArray(selectedDate.substring(0, selectedDate.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
             $(this).datepicker( "option", option, new Date(year, month, 1));
         }
     }
 });


----------
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">                                                                        
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SAProstarteDate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Start Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" validate="true" match="^(19|20)\d\d[- ](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"  error="* Please enter a valid Dispatch Date" id="SAProstarteDate" name="SAProstarteDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM" readonly="readonly">
                <div class="text-danger error" role="alert">This is the error msg!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                          
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">                                                                        
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="SAProendDate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">End Date</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" validate="true" match="^(19|20)\d\d[- ](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$"  error="* Please enter a valid Dispatch Date" id="SAProendDate" name="SAProendDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM" readonly="readonly">
                <div class="text-danger error" role="alert">This is the error msg!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                                                                          
</div>
```

How do I convert this date range (month,year) date picker to show the output of the month in numeric format- the month and date should be in numeric format (mmyy) Plz help convert this in to that format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Separately, please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The question is far too broad. What have you tried? What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I just solved this problem, and put the steps in the following link:[After changing the date format in jquery month picker, why the from<to function not works anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471397/after-changing-the-date-format-in-jquery-month-picker-why-the-fromto-function).

Just be careful of the substr function, as I made mistakes on that.